# Create a new list when I have new key while adding to Dictionary in a loop

Tags: c#, collections

I am trying to iterate a file  reading data line by line. After reading  I would like to store in Dictionary.  keys are unique but  values are having list of values for a key(may be 50 values per key). But while iterating keys comes randomly.How do I create a newlist for each key and store the value in the corresponding List when next time same key comes...how to store all those new keys and corresponding lists in dictionary.Please me on this..

Here is explanation of my code ..

```
Dictionary<String,List<PropertyCollection>> dict = new Dictionary<String,List<PropertyCollection>>(); 

List<String> list1 = new List<String>();  

//Here I am iterating the each record and getting the type and id  

for (i=1;i<datarr.length -1;i++){  

String type = datarr[3].Trim();  

String id = datarr[1].Trim();  

//here I am checking the key in map adding   

if(dict.ContainsKey(type)){  

//I need help here if the key is not there create a new record with key as "type" and values  as "id"s. All the values of same type should add in a list.If any new type comes in iteration it should add as new entry and having key and values are Ids in a list format.  


I stuck here ..


}  

}
```

I don't know how many "types " are there in that file .So I need to build the List dynamically.

```
Please help .
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: this is actually very simple to accomplish if you were to at least try something.. come on now

Comment: I have tried something .I will update my code here

Answer (score 0):

this is a pretty common scenario when working with a `Dictionary` whose value is a collection.  You just need to make sure that the collection is initialized for that key before trying to add anything to it:

```
//using Dictionary<int, List<string>>
for(int i in ...)
{
   if (!dict.ContainsKey(i))
      dict[i] = new List<string>();

   dict[i].Add("hello");
}
```

Now every new key coming in will get a fresh `List<string>`

Comment: Thank you for your answers But probably here is the main problem ..
I don't know how many keys are there earlier. and keys are string format.

Comment: Thank you for your answers But probably here is the main problem ..
I don't know how many keys are there earlier. and keys are string format.
If possible could you please give full example. I am very new to .net. Lets say if key is flower i need to  add flower related Ids to list  from file which I am reading. If key is food i need to add food related ids from file

Answer (score 0):

Class to Build your data:

```
class DataBuilder
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Data { get; } = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public void Add(string key, string dataVal)
    {
        if (!Data.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            Data.Add(key, new BaseList<string>());
        }

        Data[key].Add(dataVal);
    }
}
```

This is how you can use above class to build data while you are reading file(s):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DataBuilder();

        builder.Add("Key1", "Test Data 1");
        builder.Add("Key1", "Test Data 2");
        builder.Add("Key2", "Test Data 3");
        builder.Add("Key1", "Test Data 4");            
    }
```

Update as per your query: Change your code to this:

```
private void Process()
    {

        Dictionary<String, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<String, List<string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfRec - 1; i++)
        {
            //Code to Read record at index i into dataarr.

            String type = datarr[3].Trim();

            String id = datarr[1].Trim();

            if (!dict.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                dict.Add(type, new BaseList<string>());
            }

            dict[type].Add(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question please look at that once.

Comment: My solution still apply to your question. See my updates above.